# Why am I getting emulator error and one other error in React Native? I have followed every step provided in the react native website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. I have a good pc and followed every step to avoid any errors but still got these errors (No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`) & (':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac').

PS C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE> cd MyProject
PS C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject> npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
'"adb"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
...............10%................20%................30%................40%................50%................60%...............70%................80%................90%................100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\android\local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 37s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\android\local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 37s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)  
at C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT_NATIVE\MyProject>

I did every step provided by reactnative.dev but still got this error. Searched the internet but could'nt find any solution.

Comment: Your error message states: SDK location not found. Have you checked if you've set up your Android SDK properly? https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native#android-sdk

Comment: it sounds like you need to add some variables to PATH